# Delete records from a given table

Tags: sql

how i Delete all the artists which have not recorded any jazz titles

my artists table is :

```
artistid , artistname,city,regon
```

my titlesid Is:

```
titleid,artistid titles
```

and I tried this query

```
DELETE a.* 
FROM artists a 
     LEFT JOIN titles t ON a.artistid = t.artistid AND t.genre = 'jazz'
WHERE t.artistid IS NULL
```

but the result will delete all the artists except who have not recorded any jazz title !!!

Comment: What happens if you try `t.genre != 'jazz'`?

Comment: your query is doing exactly same as your requirement. it is deleting an artist which have not recorded any jazz titles.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, your query is doing exactly what you want. You're deleting artists who have never recorded a jazz title. If you are trying to delete only artists who have recorded a jazz title, then you would change the `WHERE` clause to be `WHERE t.artistid IS NOT NULL`, or preferably, change your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`